# Using a 3S Li-ion battery while charging

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, load

Is it possible to charge an 3s (3-cell wired in series) Li-ion battery with a balanced charger (and using the balanced charger port of the battery ofc) and connect a load to the discharge port of the battery at the same time?

For example using:

Charger: http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__7637__Turnigy_12v_2_3S_Basic_Balance_Charger.html

Battery: http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__92447__Turnigy_700mAh_3S_30C_Lipo_Pack_XT30_.html

My concern is that the charging is done by wiring the cells in a semi parallel way (all ground are tied together and each positive are going to the charger) and drawing is by connecting the cells in series - wouldn't it short circuit the battery?

Comment: Is "all ground are tied together" something you have read in the documentation, or is it just an assumption? If so, based on what?

Comment: Assumption based on the charging connector that has one black lead and 3 red leads and the understanding that a balanced charger charges each cell independently to achieve a similar voltage/charge for all cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While 'charging while using' is *possible* for a LiPo battery, it is not recommended, as it may compromise the battery safety and lifetime.

This is because the charger measures its own output current, but it does not know about the load current. The battery voltage is also lower than it would otherwise be. This means the charger incorrectly estimates both its state and rate of charge.

The idea of a standard charger charging in parallel is overwhelmingly unlikely, and can be dismissed.

Comment: The idea of a standard charger charging in parallel is not just "unlikely", it's fundamentally impossible: In order to charge the battery with the cells in parallel, the cells would first have to be disconnected from their series configuration, otherwise the cells would be shorted out.

Comment: Yes, I guess **a** charger is overwhelmingly unlikely to do that, but a **standard** charger will not. I did say the idea could be dismissed. More to the point, a standard 3S battery pack has the cells hard connected in series, so cannot be charged the freaky way.

Comment: @jms There are in fact some series packs that charge in parallel (I recall a flashlight pack that did so), but they are relatively rare.

Comment: About parallel charing, so how is the balanced charging done? as far as I understand each cell is charged independently via the balanced charger port, right? how the wiring looks like inside the battery pack?

Comment: "This means the charger incorrectly estimates both its state and rate of charge." The charger doesn't know or care about the state of charge. The SoC is the business of a Battery Management System, not of a charger. The BMS _does_ know the battery current, and therefore _can_ calculate the SoC.

Comment: Interestingly enough Infineon makes IC's that have the load, charger and battery in parallel. See seperate charge and discharge ports on this page: https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/applications/solutions/battery-management-system/battery-protection/#collapse-5d776d48-e6b8-11ea-b6ce-40f2e90e8d04-4

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may charge a string of cells at the same time as it is connected to a load. This is done a lot, for example in cellphone towers.

At any given time:

- If the load is using less current than the charger can put out, the battery will charge
- If the load is using exactly as much current as the charger can put out, the battery current is 0 (the battery neither charges nor discharges)
- If the load requires more current than the charger can provide, the battery will discharge

In other words, the battery current will be equal to the difference between the load current and the charger current.

```
battery current = load current - charger current
```

Note the sign:

```
Discharging current is positive
Charging current is negative
```

If the battery is full, the charger will naturally drop its current down to the current required by the load.

However:

Some power banks tell you not to charge and discharge at the same time. That's probably because they would overheat if both converters (charger + output DC-DC converter) are turned-on at the same time.

> charging is done by wiring the cells in a semi parallel way (all ground are tied together and each positive are going to the charger)

No, it is not. A 3S charger charges the 3S string of Li-ion cells as a string, not in parallel.

Answer (score -1):

I want to answer the question I think you wanted to ask for your use case. I think you want to know how do devices stay in use while charging. Think of a robot vacuum or your phone. These devices charge and can be "In use" at the same time because the charger actually powers the phone or end device while charging... not the battery.

To explain,

Circuits downstream of the charging voltage coming into the phone (5 VDC ~2 or so amps for a phone) direct a chunk of that to the device that balance charges the lipo cells - and cut the battery off from the load of the phone when you plug it in.

Then, the phone *load* is connected to the charger directly; and does not run off the batteries while charging. Why doesn't your phone reboot or lose power during this? Your phone uses capacitors and resistors or other charge holding devices to keep a tiny chunk of power while transitioning every time you plug it in or unplug so it does not reboot.

So, for whatever you might be making (Do this **safely** and have a very knowledgeable person review it. Messing up is asking for a house fire.) you need to switch the battery output off of the load of your device and to the load of the balance charger, and your device to some power normally provided by the batteries that the charger can yield.

If you want to have the end device experience no reboot or power loss during this, read up on Resistive capacitive circuits.